# I need to transform below input to some out put using JOLT Transformation

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I need to transform below input to exact output using JOLT transformation.
Input:

```
{
  "First_Name": "Test",
  "Last_Name": "User",
  "allpointofInterest": "someText",
  "campaign_id": "123456789",
  "lead_id": "123456789"
}
```

Output:

```
    "input" : {
    "tokens" : [ {
      "name" : "{{my.First_Name}}",
      "value" : "Test"
    }, {
      "name" : "{{my.Last_Name}}",
      "value" : "User"
    }, {
      "name" : "{{my.allpointofInterest}}",
      "value" : "someText"
    } ]
  },
  "leads": [{
      "id": "123456789"
    }]
}
```

I tried with below spec but not driven to exact output what i needed.
spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "campaign_id": ""
    }
}, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "lead_id": {
        "@": "input.leads[#1].id"
      },
      "*": "temptoken.&"
    }
}, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "temptoken": {
        "*": {
          "$": "input.tokens[#2].tmpname",
          "@": "input.tokens[#2].value"
        }
      }
    }
}, {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "input": {
        "leads": {
          "*": {
            "id": ["=toInteger", 0]
          }
        }
      }
    }
}, {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "input": {
        "tokens": {
          "*": {
            "name": "=concat('{{my.',@(1,tmpname), '}}')"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}, {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "input": {
        "tokens": {
          "*": {
            "tmpname": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
]
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does sth like that suits you?

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#{{my.First_Name}}": "input.tokens[0].name",
      "First_Name": "input.tokens[0].value",
      "#{{my.Last_Name}}": "input.tokens[1].name",
      "Last_Name": "input.tokens[1].value",
      "#{{my.allpointofInterest}}": "input.tokens[2].name",
      "allpointofInterest": "input.tokens[2].value",
      "lead_id": "leads[#].id"
    }
  }
]
```